# How to define two R7RS libraries in Guile

Tags: scheme, guile, r7rs

I have these two R7RS libraries, which I enter into the Guile REPL one by one:

```lisp
(define-library (example one)
  (import (scheme base))
  (export f)
  (begin
    (define (f x)
      (+ x 1))))

(define-library (example two)
  (import (scheme base))
  (export g)
  (begin
    (define (g x)
      (* x 2))))
```

When I enter the second library definition in the Guile REPL, I get this error:

```
While compiling expression:
Syntax error:
unknown file:13:4: definition in expression context, where definitions are not allowed, in form (define (g x) (* x 2))
```

I tried to put the two libraries into the same file (`mylibs.sld`) and ran `guile mylibs.sld`, but I get exactly the same error.

From my understanding, I am getting this error because `define-library` somehow becomes undefined by the time Guile reads the second library definition. Guile no longer knows what `define-library` means. This is strange behavior. What is going on? How do I define two R7RS libraries in the REPL?

Guile version: 3.0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to define them at the repl, you can do this by setting the current module to `(guile-user)`. Like you have guessed, after the first `define-library` the compiler is in a state where the symbols available by default in `(guile-user)` are unavailable.

So if you do a `,m (guile-user)` between defining the two libraries you will be fine.

```lisp
scheme@(guile-user)> (define-library (example one)
  (import (scheme base))
  (export f)
  (begin
    (define (f x)
      (+ x 1))))
scheme@(example one)> ,m (guile-user)
scheme@(guile-user)> (define-library (example two)
  (import (scheme base))
  (export g)
  (begin
    (define (g x)
      (* x 2))))
scheme@(example two)> ,m (guile-user)
scheme@(guile-user)> (use-modules (example one) (example two))
scheme@(guile-user)> (f 12)
$1 = 13
scheme@(guile-user)> (g 9)
$2 = 18
scheme@(guile-user)>
```

I am not sure about how to do get this to work from a single file(lib per file works fine). I tried to set the current module to `(guile-user)` with `eval-when` after the first library but even the symbol `eval-when` was unavailable. Must be a bug.

Comment: The R7RS-small standard is silent on this issue, so the inability to define more than one library per file is probably not in conflict with the standard. Chibi Scheme will also fail to understand the second `define-library` when more than one appears in a file.